# Can Youtube's Nyan Cat loading bar still be accessed?

Tags: youtube

Google changed the loading bar on the [Nyan Cat Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QH2-TGUlwu4) It used to have a little [Nyan Cat](http://www.hammerspace.tv/index.php/articles/54-internet/99-nyan-cat-loading-bar) on the loading bar, which was rainbow colored.

Can this feature still be accessed via some GET string addition or anything, or is it gone for good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature *is* gone for good. Youtube removed it, though there is a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nyan-cat-progress-bar-for/bdjaekjkckpdknkfncfnaibkabdcgmkg) that you can install to see it in effect again.